# Wordpress woocommerce paypal transaction id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, transactions, e-commerce

I am working on 2 platforms; a WordPress and a nonwordpress website. In my nonwordpress website, I can query the transaction id from Paypal. But on my WordPress is that I cannot find the transaction id on the phpmyadmin database. I found many similar questions here but it was so long ago. Can you help me out?

Comment: will depend on the payment plugin in WordPress

Comment: Hi @PrestonPHX I am just using the paypal checkout plugin on woocommerce. I tried looking at phpmyadmin as what the others pointed in their answers (the postmeta table) but nothing there.